# OpenGL - drawing GUI

Tags: opengl

I use `glm::perspective(80.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, 1.0f, 120.0f);` and multiply it by

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 60.5f),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
);
```

My question touches the subject of OpenGL and Maths. It relates to drawing GUI on my viewport. I do not know how to get proper coordinates in order to draw, e.g. a square that covers ¼ of the window. If I don't use perspectives and `glm::lookAt(...)` (matrix indentity), I will be able to draw my GUI by setting coords from X,Y in <-1.0, 1.0>. And when I put a vertex on (-1.0, -1.0), it will be localized at the bottom left corner of the window.

How to gain the same effect using perspective and lookAt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to fiddle things into one certain projection. Just switch your projection to something that better suits your GUI drawing needs. OpenGL is a state machine, and it's perfectly normal to switch the parameters multiple times throughout rendering a single image.